# Why is my code getting stuck in an infinite loop? VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to transfer information from a large matrix into a different report and this code works when I go step by step but it gets stuck in an infinite loop when I let it run without a break. Hoping to get some help if possible!

more context: Im trying to seek the information in a matrix in a different work sheet, copy information in the corresponding rows and columns, and then paste back into the original sheet with the referenced cell it is seeking

```
For k = 2 To 600

mpn = inbox.Cells(k, 3).value
If Not IsEmpty(mpn) = True Then
i = 1
j = 1
    For j = 8 To 50
        For i = 23 To 1000
        mpnsearch = wshmatrix.Cells(i, j).value
        If mpnsearch = mpn Then
             color = wshmatrix.Cells(9, j).value
              mpncolor = Right(color, 1)
             inbox.Cells(k, 5).value = mpncolor
        End If
        Next i
    Next j
End If
Next k
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: 599 x 43 x 978 = 25,190,346, so over 25 million iterations. Plus you're reading and writing cell-by-cell, so yes, this will be very slow.

Comment: It might be worthwhile for you to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Okay, im trying to seek the informatoin in a matrix in a different work sheet, copy information in the corresponding rows and columns, and then paste back into the original sheet with the referenced cell it is seeking.

Comment: Looping cell-by-cell is very slow. You should read your data into a `Variant` array and loop the array.

Comment: The answer to _Why is my code getting stuck in an infinite loop?_ is: it isn't.   It's just a very slow loop, it will eventually complete.

Comment: Depending on your data, you could build a set of `Dictionaries` for much faster access to corresponding data.

Comment: these are very helpful responses, thank you all. Im not really sure how to convert this into a variant array because the data size is always changing.

Comment: Curious:  Why don't you have screen update (and etc.) set false just before the For statement?     Consider:  for learning purposes (to discover the timing), put in a msgbox or debug.print between the next i and next j

Comment: John, just gave that a shot but its still running quite slow. I converted the hard coded numbers into a count of the rows and columns but unfortunately theyre still quite massive data sets. appreciate you all helping me out here!

Comment: I suggest switching to `Range.Find` you could quickly search through for `mpn` like `Set rFind = wshmatrix.Range(wshmatrix.Cells(23, 8), wshmatrix.Cells(1000, 50)).Find(What:=mpn, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,MatchCase:=True)`. and then you can test `rFind Is Nothing` to check if the `mpn` was found.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you have a column of values in `index`, and you need to search each of these `mpn` in a 2D matrix `wshmatrix`. The return value `mpncolor` is in the same column but in the 9th line, above your search matrix.

If you had formatted this as a lookup table (all possible `mpn` values in column 1, all `mpncolors` in column 2), this could be solved without VBA, with `VLOOKUP()`.

You can build this search table in VBA, if it is reasonably static.

If it changes frequently, you can use a `Collection` object:

```
Dim lookuptbl as New Collection
For j = 8 To 50
    For i = 23 To 1000
        lookuptbl.Add item := Right(wshmatrix.Cells(9, j).value, 1), _
                      key := CStr(wshmatrix.Cells(i, j).value)
    Next
Next

For k = 2 To 600
    mpn = inbox.Cells(k, 3).value
    inbox.Cells(k, 5).value = lookuptbl.Item(CStr(mpn))
Next
```

I did not test it right now, but I think you can get the idea.